# Should I use MB or MiB to calculate space for the system?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, disk-usage, disk-management

I'm looking to do a fresh install of Linux on my computer with a dual boot to windows. My problem is as follows

I had installed Linux before on my PC with dual boot and always followed the same process. First, install windows and use the disk manager to create empty space for Linux.

I did the exact calculations of how many Gibs I would reserve, for example, 8 * 1024 = 8192 MiB.

But when I was going to install Linux I realized that the reserved space seemed bigger and after installation Windows Disk Manager informed me different values ​​than what I wanted, partitions that should have 8 Gb They got 7.8.

With a bit of research, I found out that it was because windows used MiB while Linux used MB

Should I really care about this or can I leave the partitions with broken numbers without worrying?

Answer (score 0):

MB and GB are the most commonly used units of disk space. The Disks application in Ubuntu uses MB and GB which is logical because so do most computer hardware manufacturers and vendors when reporting the specifications of their products.